# Seemingly "orphaned" tasks in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ruby-on-rails-3, aptana, task, eclipse-indigo

I am new to Eclipse (Indigo) and using it with Aptana Studio for Ruby On Rails project. I have marked several lines in my code with "TODO" tasks, which appear in the Task view. However, there's w massive list of tasks in that view that I did not create! They don't have Resource or Path values, which made me think they're "orphaned" somehow.

What are these tasks? I went through and deleted a huge number of them but next time I started up Eclipse an even bigger list was there! How do I get rid of these?

Many thanks,
Dany.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find a dropwdown button in "Tasks" view. Then configure filtering: [image] This setting should show only todos from currently selected project, but not from all projects in your workspace.